# Add Middleware to customize TouchableOpacity behavior to add wait after onPress action to prevent multiple execution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am in the final phase of my app now I have an issue of multiple execute (when user tap multiple times) with `TouchableOpacity` component of react-native but I need to add Debounce functionality with every `TouchableOpacity` used in my app. So, I used [this](https://medium.com/@devmrin/debouncing-touch-events-in-react-native-prevent-navigating-twice-or-more-times-when-button-is-90687e4a8113) article of medium and create a custom component. below is my component but in this case I need to change every `TouchableOpacity` to `TouchableDebounce`.

So, My requirement is I want to add a middleware or something to change the behavior of `TouchableOpacity` by this we I don't need to do changes in every class of my app. Is there any way to do this?

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import _ from 'lodash';

const TouchableDebounce = props => (
  <TouchableOpacity
    {...props}
    onPress={
      _.debounce(props.onPress, props.debounceTime, props.options)
    }
  >
    {props.children}
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

TouchableDebounce.propTypes = {
  onPress: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.element,
  options: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any),
  debounceTime: PropTypes.number,
};
TouchableDebounce.defaultProps = {
  children: null,
  options: { 'leading': true, 'trailing': false },
  debounceTime: 500,
};
export default TouchableDebounce;
```

Comment: Why do you want to prevent multiple execution ? is it because of some async action you're executing ?

Comment: You can checkout `debounceTime` operator in `rxjs`. That's what I used for a similar case at least.

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli I updated my question.
@Javascriptonian I already created my debounce component but I want to do it by direct modify `TouchableOpacity` as I describe above.

Comment: @Nitish I could suggest a solution that's require a change in your `import` statement of your `TouchableOpacity` component  on every location of your code that  uses it

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli Do you mean As I created the component above just import it and replace it with `TouchableOpacity` all places where I am using or you have other way?